# Unable to fetch user group member ship using MS graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

Mine is an ASP MVC web app (.Net framework 4.6.2), I’m using Azure Active Directory for authentication and authorization.
Under Startup.Auth.cs file I’m using app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication => AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => {}

any idea on how to get group membership of a user using context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity ?

```
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager()),
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters { RoleClaimType = "roles" },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
            {
                var code = context.Code;
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                List<System.Security.Claims.Claim> claims = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.ToList<System.Security.Claims.Claim>();
```